# Не совсем понимаю как работает метод max() в python

Tags: python

Есть список цифр:

```
a = ['7', '8', '3', '-5', '42', '-1', '0', '0', '-9', '49', '7', '4', '-4']
```

Если я сделаю:

```
print(max(a))
```

То получу ответ **8**, хотя должно быть **49**. Почему так?

Comment: Потому что это не список цифр, это список строк, а строки сортируются по алфавиту

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Решил так с вашей подсказки list(map(int, a))

Answer (score 8):

Потому что элементы списка имеют тип `str` а не `int` у вас два способа
либо добавить в список числа а не строки

```
a = [7, 8, 3, -5, 42, -1, 0, 0, -9, 49, 7, 4, -4]

print(max(a))
```

вывод:

```
49
```

либо ваш код преобразовать в `int`

```
a = ['7', '8', '3', '-5', '42', '-1', '0', '0', '-9', '49', '7', '4', '-4']

print(max(a, key = int))
```

вывод:

```
49
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня еще сработало max(list(map(int, a)))

Comment: `lambda` можно заменить на просто `int`

Comment: @Danis Что то не пойму каким образом

Comment: @Danis Извиняюсь, тупанул, согласен

Answer (score 1):

Можно и не преобразуя строковые значения получить правильную сортировку и взять максимум. Такое тоже бывает нужно. Но придётся использовать библиотеку, впрочем она часто уже стоит во многих дистрибутивах:

```py
import natsort

a = ['7', '8', '3', '-5', '42', '-1', '0', '0', '-9', '49', '7', '4', '-4']
print(natsort.realsorted(a)[-1])
# 49
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что элементы списка a - это строки, а не числа. Функция max сравнивает строки лексикографически (по алфавиту), поэтому она считает, что '7' > '8', а '8' > '3' и так далее. Чтобы получить максимальное число в списке, нужно преобразовать элементы списка в числа с помощью функции int:

```
a = [7, 8, 3, -5, 42, -1, 0, 0, -9, 49, 7, 4, -4]
print(max(a)) # 49
```

То же самое касается функции min. Чтобы получить минимальное число в списке, нужно также преобразовать элементы списка в числа:

```
a = [7, 8, 3, -5, 42, -1, 0, 0, -9, 49, 7, 4, -4]
print(min(a)) # -9
```

Вот несколько примеров:

## Список чисел

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(max(numbers)) # 6
print(min(numbers)) # 1
```

## Список дробных чисел

```
decimals = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
print(max(decimals)) # 0.6
print(min(decimals)) # 0.1
```

## Список строк

```
strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(max(strings)) # 'f'
print(min(strings)) # 'a'
```

## Список смешанных типов

```
mixed = ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c']
print(max(mixed)) # 'c'
print(min(mixed)) # 1
```

## Список с отрицательными числами

```
negatives = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]
print(max(negatives)) # -1
print(min(negatives)) # -6
```

---

Если вам нужно найти максимальное или минимальное число в списке, состоящем из строк, то вы можете сначала преобразовать строки в числа с помощью функции int и затем вызвать функции max и min:

## Список строк

```
a = ['7', '8', '3', '-5', '42', '-1', '0', '0', '-9', '49', '7', '4', '-4']
```

## Преобразуем строки в числа

```
a = [int(x) for x in a]

print(max(a)) # 49
print(min(a)) # -9
```

Также можно использовать функцию map для преобразования строк в числа:

```
a = ['7', '8', '3', '-5', '42', '-1', '0', '0', '-9', '49', '7', '4', '-4']
a = list(map(int, a))

print(max(a)) # 49
print(min(a)) # -9
```

Также можно использовать функцию sorted, чтобы отсортировать список и получить максимальное и минимальное число:

```
a = ['7', '8', '3', '-5', '42', '-1', '0', '0', '-9', '49', '7', '4', '-4']
a = sorted([int(x) for x in a])

print(a[-1]) # 49 (последний элемент списка - это максимальное число)
print(a[0]) # -9 (первый элемент списка - это минимальное число)
```

Answer (score -2):

Находить максимум и минимум нужно среди типа данных int, или  float.Правильно будет так

a = [7, 8, 3, -5, 42, -1, 0, 0, -9, 49, 7, 4, -4]

```
print(max(a))
```